# Knockout js sort function only sort 2 items in the array

Tags: javascript, sorting, knockout.js

I searched online for my issue but it seems i can't make it work.

Here is how any item in the list looks like (parsed JSon) :

```
    actualDate: "2017-11-25T00:00:00.000Z"
    expectedDate: "2017-11-17T00:00:00.000Z"
    id: 2
    initialDate: "2017-11-17T00:00:00.000Z"
    isDone: false
    markerTitle: "Test"
    markerTypeId: 1
    projectId: 11
```

And here's my sorting function:

```
    self.listOfMarkers(self.listOfMarkers().sort(function (m1, m2)
    {
        var d1 = (m1.actualDate === null ? (m1.expectedDate === null ? 
        m1.initialDate : m1.expectedDate) : m1.actualDate);
        var d2 = (m2.actualDate === null ? (m2.expectedDate === null ? 
        m2.initialDate : m2.expectedDate) : m2.actualDate);

        return d1 < d2 ? -1 : 1;
    }));
```

This function is executed in the callBack function of my update of an item.
I managed to sort it in C# on my API side but on the front side it's only sorting 2 items.

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Haven't read through all of the code, but the problem might be that you don't return `0` for equal dates: `return d1 < d2 ? 1: d1 > d2 ? -1 : 0;`

Comment: Hi, i tried with this : return d1 === d2 ? 0 : (d1 < d2 ? -1 : 1); but it did the same.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue (took some short cuts with es6 syntax, but base is the same), but could not: https://jsfiddle.net/udetrjnp/ Any idea on what you did differently?

Comment: Hey, i think the difference is on the sorting function. I copied yours and it seems to work.
I think the intermediate vars i created or the way i'm getting the good dates was the issue.
Anyway, thx for your help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer myself as i found the solution with the help of user3297291 in the comments above.

Changing the sorting function to this solved the issue :

```
    self.listOfMarkers(self.listOfMarkers().sort(function (m1, m2) {
        m1 = m1.actualDate || m1.expected || m1.initialDate;
        m2 = m2.actualDate || m2.expected || m2.initialDate;

        return m1 > m2 ? 1 : m1 < m2 ? -1 : 0;
    }));
```

I think using intermediates vars or the way i'm getting the right date was the issue.